# AddComponent<T>

Tags: c#, unity3d

В старых версиях можно было написать так:

```
void Test (Type meType) {
   gameObject.AddComponent(meType.Name);
}
```

Но `AddComponent(string)` устарела и осталость только `AddComponent<T>()`.

Как это написать сейчас?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перегрузку со строковым названием компонентов убрали (и это хорошо), но никто не убирал перегрузку с типом:

`public Component AddComponent(Type componentType);`

Поэтому никто не запрещает делать так:

```
void Test (Type meType) {
   gameObject.AddComponent(meType);
}
```